# Laravel validation doesn't validate html entities

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm working with Laravel 5.5 and I'm trying to make validation of a form which shouldn't pass if user write html entities, for example: `<h1>Hola</h1>`, `<script>alert(1)</script>`.
But it insert all field in DB.

My controller:

```
protected function storeForm(CaseRequest $request){
try {
$supportCase = new SupportCase;
$supportCase->type = $request->input('type');
// all fields of table[...]
$supportCase->save();

return view('steps/finish/success')->with(['message' => 'Form success']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
          echo $e->getMessage();
          return view('steps/finish/error')->withErrors(['message' => 'Form error']);
      }
}
```

My CaseRequest is this:

```
 /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
          'type' => 'required|min:3|max:3|string',
          'brand' => 'required|string',
          'product' => 'required|string',
          'order' => 'required|string',
          'description' => 'required|min:10|string',
          'sn' => 'nullable',
          'name' => 'required|min:2|string',
          'nin' => 'required|min:9|max:11|alpha_dash',
          'email' => 'required|email',
          'phone' => 'required|digits_between:7,12',
          'address' => 'required|min:5|string',
          'city' => 'required|min:2|string',
          'zip' => 'required|min:2|numeric',
          'state' => 'required|min:2|string',
          'country' => 'required|min:2|string',
        ];
    }
```

I have read the documentation and the Request is the first to be called, before than controller, and if this has any error it throw a error message. Doesn't it?.

I'm using parsley and select2, at first it has a validation in frontend with parley, and it's working well, but if I remove parsley validation now Laravel should validate it, right? but in my DB it is saving all fields (included`<script>alert(1)</script>`).

```
    <div class="form" id="main-form" data-parsley-validate="data-parsley-validate">
        {!! Form::open(['id' => 'main-form', 'data-parsley-validate' => 'data-parsley-validate']) !!}

        <div class="col-md-7 light-form">
            <fieldset>
                {!! Form::label('contact', trans('frontend/steps.form.contact'), ['class' => 'upper']) !!}
                {!! Form::label('name',  trans('frontend/steps.form.name')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('name', old('name'), [
                                                    'data-parsley-pattern' => '[ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúa-zA-Z ]+$',
                                                    'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                                    'data-parsley-minlength'=>'2',
                                                    'data-parsley-required-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.name'),
                                                    'data-parsley-minlength-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.name'),
                                                    'data-parsley-pattern-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.name'),

                                                    ]) !!}
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                {!! Form::label('nin',  trans('frontend/steps.form.in')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('nin', old('nin'), [
                                                  'data-parsley-type'=>'alphanum',
                                                  'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                                  'data-parsley-minlength'=>'9',
                                                  'data-parsley-maxlength'=>'11',
                                                  'data-parsley-required-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.in'),
                                                  'data-parsley-minlength-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.in'),
                                                  'data-parsley-maxlength-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.in')
                                                  ]) !!}
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                {!! Form::label('phone',  trans('frontend/steps.form.telf')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('phone', old('phone'), [
                'data-parsley-pattern' => '\d+$',
                                                  'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                                  'data-parsley-minlength'=>'7',
                                                  'data-parsley-maxlength'=>'12',
                                                  'data-parsley-required-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.telf'),
                                                  'data-parsley-minlength-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.telf'),
                                                  'data-parsley-maxlength-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.telf'),
                                                  'data-parsley-pattern-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.telf')
                                                  ]) !!}
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                {!! Form::label('address',  trans('frontend/steps.form.address')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('address', old('address'), [
                        'data-parsley-pattern' => '^[ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúa-zA-Z0-9-_ ]+$',
                        'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                        'data-parsley-minlength'=>'5',
                        'data-parsley-pattern-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.address'),
                        'data-parsley-minlength-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.address'),
                        'data-parsley-required-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.address'),

                                                  ]) !!}
            </fieldset>

            <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
                <div class="col-md-6 location-form">
                    <fieldset>
                        {!! Form::label('address',  trans('frontend/steps.form.city')) !!}
                        {!! Form::text('city', old('city'), [
                                                          'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                                          'data-parsley-minlength'=>'2',
                                                          'data-parsley-pattern' => '[ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúa-zA-Z ]+$',
                                                          'data-parsley-minlength-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.city'),
                                                          'data-parsley-required-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.city'),
                                                          'data-parsley-pattern-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.city'),
                                                          ]) !!}
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        {!! Form::label('zip',  trans('frontend/steps.form.zip')) !!}
                        {!! Form::text('zip', old('zip'), [
                                                          'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                                          'data-parsley-minlength'=>'2',
                                                          'data-parsley-minlength-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.zip'),
                                                          'data-parsley-required-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.zip')
                                                          ]) !!}
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 no-padding">
                    <fieldset>
                        {!! Form::label('state',  trans('frontend/steps.form.state')) !!}
                        {!! Form::text('state', old('state'), [
                                                          'data-parsley-pattern' => '[ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúa-zA-Z ]+$',
                                                          'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                                          'data-parsley-minlength'=>'2',
                                                          'data-parsley-required-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.state'),
                                                          'data-parsley-minlength-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.state'),
                                                          'data-parsley-pattern-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.state'),
                                                          ]) !!}
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        {!! Form::label('country',  trans('frontend/steps.form.country')) !!}
                        {!! Form::text('country', old('country'), [
                                                          'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                                          'data-parsley-pattern' => '[ÁÉÍÓÚáéíóúa-zA-Z ]+$',
                                                          'data-parsley-minlength'=>'2',
                                                          'data-parsley-required-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.country'),
                                                          'data-parsley-minlength-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.country'),
                                                          'data-parsley-pattern-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.country'),
                                                          ]) !!}
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 dark-form">
            <fieldset>
                {!! Form::label('order', trans('frontend/steps.form.order'), ['class' => 'upper']) !!}
                {!! Form::text('order', old('order'), [
                                                  'placeholder' => '123567',
                                                  'data-parsley-type' => 'digits',
                                                  'data-parsley-type-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.order_format'),
                                                  'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                                  'data-parsley-required-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.order')
                                                  ]) !!}
                <span class="loading style-2"></span>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="brand-wrap">
                <label class="upper" for="brand">
                    {!!  trans('frontend/steps.form.brand') !!}
                    <img class="tip" title="{!! trans('frontend/steps.form.brand_tooltip') !!}"
                         src="{!! asset('assets/img/frontend/icons/info.png') !!}"/>
                </label>
                {!! Form::select('brand', $layout->brands->pluck('name', 'id'), old('brand'), [
                                                                                                'id'=> 'brand',
                                                                                                'class' => 'select2',
                                                                                                'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                                                                                'data-parsley-required-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.brand')
                                                                                                ])
                                                                                          !!}
                <span class="loading style-2"></span>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="product-wrap">
                {!! Form::label('product', trans('frontend/steps.form.product'), ['class' => 'upper']) !!}
                {!! Form::select('product', ['null' => 'null'], old('product'), [
                                                                                'id'=> 'product_select',
                                                                                'class' => 'select2',
                                                                                'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                                                                'data-parsley-required-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.product')
                                                                                ])
                                                                          !!}
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                {!! Form::label('description', trans('frontend/steps.form.problem'), ['class' => 'upper']) !!}
                {!! Form::textarea('description', old('description'), [
                                                'data-parsley-pattern' => '[áéíóúÁÉÍÓÚäëïöüÄËÏÖÜa-zA-Z0-9-_ ]+$',
                                                'data-parsley-minlength'=>'10',
                                                'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                                'data-parsley-type-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.problem'),
                                                'data-parsley-required-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.problem'),
                                                'data-parsley-minlength-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.problem'),
                                                'data-parsley-pattern-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.problem')
                                                  ]) !!}
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset id="serial-wrap">
                {!! Form::label('sn', trans('frontend/steps.form.serial')) !!}
                {!! Form::text('sn', old('sn'), [
                                                'id' => 'sn',
                                                'data-parsley-required' => 'false',
                                                'data-parsley-required-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.imei'),
                                                'data-parsley-lunhvalidator' => '15',
                                                'data-parsley-lunhvalidator-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.invalid-imei')
                                                ])
                                            !!}
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                {!! Form::label('email',  trans('frontend/steps.form.email')) !!}
                {!! Form::email('email', old('email'), [
                                                  'data-parsley-type'=> 'email',
                                                  'data-parsley-required' => 'true',
                                                  'data-parsley-type-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.email'),
                                                  'data-parsley-required-message' => trans('frontend/steps.form-errors.email')
                                                  ]) !!}
            </fieldset>

            @if($case == "INC")
                <button class="upper" type="button" onclick="nextStep(this)" data-type="FORM" data-field="transaction"
                        data-next="eleventh" data-case="{!! $case !!}"
                        data-value="">{!! trans('frontend/steps.form.continue') !!}</button>
            @else
                <button class="upper" type="button" onclick="nextStep(this)" data-type="FORM" data-field="transaction"
                        data-next="fifth" data-case="{!! $case !!}"
                        data-value="">{!! trans('frontend/steps.form.continue') !!}</button>
            @endif
        </div>
        {!! Form::close() !!}
    </div>
```

Comment: Usually you don't care about saving HTML in your database, just escape it when outputting. (Laravel does it by default with `{{ $var }}`)

Comment: But I don't want to save HTML in my DB, because I will use this information. I thought Laravel was doing this

Comment: Can you post your form here ?

Comment: I included it in post

Answer (score 2):

Validation doesn't change input data. It just ensures the input matches your defined rules.

Technically there is no need to remove HTML tags. They won't do any harm in the database and can be escaped when outputting with `{{ $content }}`.

If you don't want to save HTML in your database use [`strip_tags()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) on the relevant fields.
**But don't rely on it to prevent XSS, escaping output is still necessary**